# Auto merge master branch into staging branch, whenever there are any changes made in master branch

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch

I have two branches `Master` and `Staging`. Whenever a PR is merged or any other changes are done into `Master` branch directly, then I need to merge `Master` branch back to `Staging` branch automatically.
Is this possible to do through git, or I have to write a script?

Comment: "automatically"? Is it not rather "manually" and you want to reach the "automatically"-approach?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen didn't get you

Comment: So please change the question!